# How to update the object attributes in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have recently started using protractor with jasmine framework and i am new to javascript as well.
For one of the page with 10 attributes, i am trying to getText for each field and update this value in an object. Following is the example code

```
Var obj ={}

It('should get the value,function(){
    Element(by.id("id of firstfield")).getText().then(function(text){
        obj.firstfield = text
        Console.log(obj) //this correctly prints the updated object
    })

    Console.log(obj) // prints empty object. I need to get updated object here.

    Element (by.id("id of secondfield")).getText().then(function(text){
        obj.secondfield = text
        Console.log(obj) //this correctly prints the updated object
    })
})
```

How to get the values outof .then?

Comment: Sounds like it would help you to read up on how Promises work in JavaScript - this is a good starting resource: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 1):

Changes made to variables inside .then block are not reflected outside the block. To make the changes visible outside the .then block, use the return statement and collect the returned value in a variable.

Return the updated value to the obj and then print via .then

```
obj = Element(by.id("id of firstfield")).getText().then(function(text){
    obj.firstfield = text
    Console.log(obj) //this correctly prints the updated object
    return obj;
})
```

See if this helps!

Comment: Adding more explanation on why the current approach is not working would make it a better answer.

Comment: Added explanation! Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: This didnt work. The output was {then [function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending]

Comment: This is a Promise! Can you tell me the exact code you used for printing

Comment: Nope. Do as u would do for resolving a Promise. obj.then(function(obj1){console.log(obj1);});

Comment: ok. It worked. However I want to update 10 attributes in an object which are values from 10 different fields on UI. Any help in that would be great.

Comment: If your obj is an array, I think the following should work:
obj[obj.length] = text; Let me know if this helps!